# data manipulation for data.frame based on column index

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` as follow,

```
A <- sample(1:10,5)
B <- sample(11:20, 5)
C <- sample(21:30, 5)
index <- sample(1:3,5, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(A,B,C,index)

> data
   A  B  C index
1  9 17 30     3
2 10 15 26     2
3  2 19 23     2
4  3 13 29     2
5  8 12 25     2
```

my desired output would be

```
> data$output <- c(30,15,19,13,12)
> data
   A  B  C index output
1  9 17 30     3     30
2 10 15 26     2     15
3  2 19 23     2     19
4  3 13 29     2     13
5  8 12 25     2     12
```

The idea is that index indicate the number of column i would like to extract. for example for second row, index is 2, then output should be B:15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat trick to avoid using, e.g., a loop, is to use a matrix to subset the data frame. Let's first generate a matrix, which specifies the 'cells' to be extracted:

```
m<-matrix(ncol=2, data=c(as.numeric(rownames(data)), data$index))
```

Now matrix m has to columns, the first for the row index and second for the column index of the data frame. Note that you might need to adjust the `as.numeric(rownames(data))` part accordingly, if your row names are not in ascending order. But this solution works for the example data.

Then subsetting the data frame using this matrix simply as:

```
data[m]
```

should yield the correct result. You can then assign it to the data frame an output column:

```
data$output<-data[m]
```

This is documented in the help file for the [ operator. See `?"["` and spefically the note "When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.".

Comment: I would use: `transform(data, output=data[cbind(1:nrow(data), index)])`

Comment: @akrun, that would the right solution. I was trying to do the same, but probably messed somehow the syntax (put the `index` first by midstake)

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach (should be more efficient)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, output := .SD[, index, with = F], by = index]

#     A  B  C index output
# 1:  9 17 30     3     30
# 2: 10 15 26     2     15
# 3:  2 19 23     2     19
# 4:  3 13 29     2     13
# 5:  8 12 25     2     12
```

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
data$output <- t(data[,-4])[data$index+(0:4)*3] #0:4 denotes 1-(1:nrow(data)); 
                       #3 is ncol(data[,-4])
data$output 
#[1] 30 15 19 13 12
```